# Modify figure block to nested div for ckeditor5 elements

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor5, inline-scripting, ckeditor5-plugin

Thanks.
I downloaded ckeditor5 custom build using online builder.
Integrated with php application and writing script within view page,
On uploaded image im getting source as

```
<figure><img src:"uploaded path"></figure>
```

its is working fine but I want to change is as

```
<div class="outerDiv"><div class:"InnerDiv"><img src:"uploaded path"></div></div>
```

Could you please help?